# Drools Get Object That Has The Higher Priority

Tags: java, drools

I want to know if we could get the object that has the higher priority using drools accumulate expression?
Here is my code:

```
rule "dropShiftWithTheLowestPriorityTaskForWeekdayMorningShiftReassignment"
when 
    ShiftAssignment( isNeedToReassign == true, shiftType.code == 'E', weekend == false,  
        $shiftDate : shiftDate, 
        $shiftType : shiftType )

    $max : Number(intValue >= 0) from accumulate(
        $assignment : ShiftAssignment(
            weekend == false,
            shiftDate == $shiftDate,
            shiftType == $shiftType, 
            $totalWeight : totalWeight),
        max($totalWeight)
    )
then
    System.out.println('----------');
    System.out.println('max='+$max);
```

I just get the max totalWeight, but I don't know how I can get the object that contains that totalWeight. 
Please help me, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a similar question posted some days ago:
[How to get max min item from a list in Drools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28994984/how-to-get-max-min-item-from-a-list-in-drools/29003964?noredirect=1#comment46342082_29003964)

There are 2 solutions posted there:

1. Create your own accumulate function
2. Use 2 simple patterns

Following the first approach, you would need to write something like this:

```
when
    $maxAssignment: ShiftAssignment() from accumulate(
        $sa: ShiftAssignment(),        
        init( ShiftAssignment max = null; ),
        action( if( max == null || max.totalWeight < $sa.totalWeight ){
            max = $sa;
        } ),
        result( max ) )
then
    //$maxAssignment contains the ShiftAssignment with the highest weight. 
end
```

Please note that this implementation should be used only for prototyping or testing purposes. It is considered a good practice to implement your custom accumulate functions in Java.

Following the second approach, your rule could be re-written as:

```
when 
    $maxAssignment: ShiftAssignment(..., $maxWeight: totalWeight)
    not ShiftAssignment(..., totalWeight > $maxWeight)
then
    //$maxAssignment contains the ShiftAssignment with the highest weight. 
end
```

Hope it helps,